# Haskell Regular Expression behaving differently:

Tags: regex, haskell

Say I have the following regex to validate dates are of the format 'YYYY-MM-DD':

`([12]\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))`

Using any number of online regex testers. (I like https://regex101.com/), it becomes obvious that this works (e.g: 2055-12-12 parses correctly, 2055-13-25 fails to parse.

Now in haskell:

```
  import Text.Regex.TDFA
  import Text.Regex.TDFA.Text ()
  let dateRegex = "([12]\\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\\d|3[01]))" :: Text
  let fromDate' = "2055-12-12"
  putStrLn((fromDate' =~ dateRegex)::Text)
```

produces the empty string - failing to match. I have no idea why. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Those are perl-style regular expressions (in particular `\d`), which are not supported (it's written in the regex-tdfa package docs). Not sure about eg. `{3}` either. The docs suggest regex-pcre, or you can use posix-style expressions eg. `[[:digit:]]`.

Comment: @moonGoose Please write an answer when you get the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\d` meaning digit is a feature of perl-style regular expressions. The docs for regex-tdfa state that it implements posix extended, not perl-style. Your choices are therefore to rewrite with posix character classes ie. using `[[:digit:]]`,

`dateRegex = "([12][[:digit:]]{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12][[:digit:]]|3[01]))"`

or instead `import "regex-pcre" Text.Regex.PCRE` with your original regex.

Answer (score 0):

In Haskell, the usual advice is [**Parse, don't validate**](https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2019/11/05/parse-don-t-validate/).

```
import Text.Megaparsec
import Text.Megaparsec.Char
import Data.Time.Calendar
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Fail
import Text.Read
import Data.Maybe
import Data.Void

parseDay :: Parsec Void String Day
parseDay = do
  y <- maybe (fail "bad year") pure =<< readMaybe <$> replicateM 4 digitChar
  chunk "-"
  m <- maybe (fail "bad month") pure =<< readMaybe <$> replicateM 2 digitChar
  chunk "-"
  d <- maybe (fail "bad day") pure =<< readMaybe <$> replicateM 2 digitChar
  maybe (fail "not a Gregorian calendar day") pure $ fromGregorianValid y m d
 
runParser parseDay "" "2020-11-30"
```

```
Right 2020-11-30
```